For $f: T\to S, v : \mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{O}_S$ and $j :\mathrm{im} (v) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_S$, $f^{*}(v)=0$ if and only if $f^{*}(j) =0$?
Let $f: T \to S$ be a morphism of schemes. Let $v : \mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{O}_S$ be a homomorphim of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_S$-modules. Let $\mathcal{J}:=\mathrm{im}(v)$ be the image of $v$ and $j :\mathrm{im} (v) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_S$ be the inclustion.
Then my question is, $f^{*}(v)=0$ if and only if $f^{*}(j) =0$?
It suffices to show that $f^{*}(v)_t=0$ for all $t\in T$ if and only if $f^{*}(j)_t =0$ for all $t\in T$. Note that the domain and codomain of $f^{*}(v)_t, f^{*}(j)_t$ are ( noting $ v_{f(t)} : \mathcal{L}_{f(t)} \to \mathcal{O}_{S,f(t)}. $ )
$$ f^{*}(j)_t : f^{*}(\mathrm{im} (v))_t:=\mathcal{O}_{T,t} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,f(t)}} \mathrm{im}(v_{f(t)}) \to \mathcal{O}_{T,t}  $$
$$ f^{*}(v)_t: f^{*}(\mathcal{L})_t := \mathcal{O}_{T,t} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,f(t)}}\mathcal{L}_{f(t)} \to \mathcal{O}_{T,t} $$
From these can we make further progress?
Perhaps, next is true?
Set $f:= f^{*}(j)_t, g:=f^{*}(v)_t$, $ \varphi : A:=\mathcal{O}_{S,f(t)} \to B:=\mathcal{O}_{T,t}$ be the algebra structure. Let $v:=v_{f(t)} : L:=\mathcal{L}_{f(t)} \to A$.
Then $f: B \otimes_A (\mathrm{im}v) \to B$ is given by $(b \otimes a) \mapsto ab:= \varphi(a)b$ and $g: B\otimes_A L \to B$ is given by $(b\otimes l)\mapsto v(l) \cdot b:=\varphi(v(l)) b $? If so then I could prove $f=0$ if and only if $g=0$, as desired. And is it true? Can anyone help?

After some consideration, I think that one of key point is,

$f^{-1}(v)_t = v_{f(t)}$ and $f^{-1}(j)_t=j_{f(t)} : \mathrm{im}(v_{f(t)}) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{S,f(t)}$ is the natural inclustion.

( $\because $ $f^{-1}(\varphi)_{x} = \varphi_{f(x)}$ ( Stalk of the inverse image )? )
If so, then note that
$$f^{*}(j)_t = \mathcal{O}_{T,t} \otimes_{(f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S)_t} f^{-1}(j)_t =\mathcal{O}_{T,t} \otimes_{(f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S)_t} j_{f(t)} = \mathcal{O}_{T,t} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,f(t)}} j_{f(t)} $$
$$ f^{*}(v)_t = \mathcal{O}_{T,t} \otimes_{(f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S)_t} f^{-1}(v)_t =\mathcal{O}_{T,t} \otimes_{(f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_S)_t} v_{f(t)}=
 \mathcal{O}_{T,t} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,f(t)}} v_{f(t)} . $$
So, upto $\mathcal{O}_{T,t} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,f(t)}} \mathcal{O}_{S,f(t)} \cong \mathcal{O}_{T,t}$ ($b \otimes a \mapsto b \varphi(a)$) , we have :
$$f^{*}(j)_t  : ( b \otimes a ) \mapsto (b\otimes j_{f(t)}(a) ) = b\otimes a \mapsto b \cdot a := \varphi(a) b $$
$$ f^{*}(v)_t : (b \otimes l ) \mapsto (b \otimes v_{f(t)}(l)) \mapsto b \cdot v_{f(t)}(l) := \varphi(v_{f(t)}(l)) b .$$
So the above interlude question in my post is true and we are done.
